# ProGuards always removing method call

Tags: java, methods, proguard

Proguard removing my method from runnable, but ONLY if I add this class with runnable (nested class) to exceptions...

So... If I add it to exceptions by -keep then why remove method call? (this is the only one line in this runnable, and it removing it...)

```
Main.createTask(pl, new Runnable()
{

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            myMethod(false);
        } catch (final IOException e)
        {
            Main.log(Level.WARNING, "...");
        }
    }

});
```

And after proguard...

```
Main.createTask(pl, new Runnable()
{

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try{} catch (final IOException e)
        {
            Main.log(Level.WARNING, "...");
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

ProGuard's optimization step may remove the method in two cases:

- Calling the method has no effect whatsoever.
- You have specified `-assumenosideeffects` with arguments that match the method. It's a dangerous option to use with wildcards. You can easily remove or comment out all `-assumenosideeffects` options to check if this is the reason.

If you're inspecting the processed code with a decompiler, you may want to check that the decompiler is working properly. You could double-check with `javap -c`.

Comment: Hyyym... I actually "solved" this problem by disable shrinking. And decompiler must work, because I also tested that in run. Hyym... method is sending data to web page, that can be a reason?